# How does an SMU change its output impedance from current source mode to voltage source mode?

Tags: current-source, feedback, voltage-source, test-equipment

[image: V/I control and readback]

[image: output stage]

[image]

The above three figures are from the Keithley 237 SMU service manual.
From my understanding, the system is configured as a famous two OPAMP precision current-pump topology (shown [here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/how-to-design-a-precision-current-pump-with-op-amps/)).

Although I still haven't fully figured out how the feedback associated with 'IDAC, U17, U13, Amps ranging, and U3' is configured, I guess this is some sort of a series-series feedback that increases the output impedance by its loop gain.

However, I don't know how such system can be modified when it is switched to the voltage-source mode output. In this mode, the output impedance must be minimized to avoid any voltage loss at the load side.

To minimize the output impedance, I can think of only two possible solutions:

1. There is a hidden unity-gain buffer located right before the 'Out+' port, and this unity-gain buffer path is available only when the output mode is set to voltage.
2. U12 and U19 with V-feedback configures the system as a series-shunt feedback. This way, the output impedance can be decreased by a factor of its loop gain.

I would appreciate it if anyone could point out which of my thought processes among the two is correct or if I am missing something else.

**EDIT:** I just derived its output impedance for two cases: I-DAC driving error amp vs V-DAC driving error amp. Indeed, the output impedance is multiplied by its loopgain when I-DAC is driving. For V-DAC case, the output impedance reduces down to the resistance of the amp-ranging section, approximately. I guess the output impedance indeed changes by choosing which DAC drives the error amplifier in this case. please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Max/minimized at what time scales (frequencies)? If you mean at DC (resistance), that's ensured by error amps.

Comment: @TimWilliams at DC. What do you mean by it is 'ensured' by the error amp? what is ensured and how it is ensured?

Comment: ...Perhaps a more rudimentary question on error amp function would be called for (or searching for such answers)?

Comment: @TimWilliams I understand what error amplifier does. My question was more like how the output impedance can be changing from high to low when the mode is changed from current to voltage mode. Did you actually read my question?

Comment: It's simply one error amp or the other taking priority. If you understand how an error amp can make high-Z, or low-Z (individually, by configuration), then that's all you need to know: there exists a way to switch between such configurations, live.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148076/discussion-between-emm386-and-tim-williams).